# How to make an auto increment number based on a year

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a simple C# Windows Forms application where a custom auto increment number should be there, it will be used as a serial number for each application.

How can I make this custom number reset ***based on the year*** ?

**2019**

```
serial number: 1/2019
serial number: 2/2019
serial number: 3/2019
serial number: 4/2019
.
.
.
serial number: 200/2019
```

**2020**

```
serial number: 1/2020
serial number: 2/2020
serial number: 3/2020
serial number: 4/2020
serial number: 5/2020
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? It's not clear to me why you don't just increment a number and stick the current year on the end. Do you mean you want to do this automatically in a database column?

Comment: Please show the current process you're using so we can suggest how to fix it.

Comment: Unless this is an isolated, academic exercise, you're going to run into problems with this kind of design unless you at least define the "keeper of the last value" so that something doesn't create a new value in 2019 unaware that you've moved on to 2020.

Comment: Is this a database issue?  Where are you storing this information?

Comment: I have tried a lot of stuff, the code looks messy and non-understandable that's why I didn't share anything, just to keep the question neat, of course it will be be stored in database, I will be keeping the auto increment ID column as it is and use it for search, sort, etc.. and I have created a separate column for this custom serial number, it is defiantly not an academic exercise, I don't think there will be any trouble if using such logic, the problem is how to make the software aware that we have entered 2020 so reset the serial and add the year value after the slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out myself and thank you for the down votes

```
public class SerialNumber
{
    private static readonly MyDbContext DbContext = new MyDbContext();

    public static string SrNo()
    {
        var sn = DbContext.PrimaryForms.ToList().Last().FormDescription;

        var array = sn.Split('/');

        if (int.Parse(array[0]) == DateTime.Today.Year)
        {
            return array[0] + "/" + (int.Parse(array[1]) + 1);
        }

        return (int.Parse(array[0]) + 1) + "/1";
    }
}
```

if code is not clear, ask me for explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to simply store a map of the last used id along with the current year, which should be done in a database but could also be done in a dictionary (which is easier to show in a code sample):

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, int> YearIdMap = new Dictionary<int, int>();

public static string GetNextId()
{
    // Get the current year
    int year = DateTime.Today.Year;

    // Something to store the next id value in
    int nextId;

    // Sets nextId to the current id for this year, or 0 if there isn't one yet
    YearIdMap.TryGetValue(year, out nextId); 

    // Increment our number
    nextId++;

    // Save the new value along with this year
    YearIdMap[year] = nextId;

    // Return the value to the caller in the format: id/year
    return $"{nextId}/{year}";
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, and perhaps a bit rhetorical, but since this is based on the current year, can one really expect this to stay in memory long enough for this to track more than two distinct years? Perhaps persistence is out of scope (in this question).

Comment: @madreflection Yeah, that's why I said using a database (or even the file system) would be better. This was more to show a process of setting a variable to the current value for the year (or setting it to zero if there isn't one), incrementing it, saving the result, and returning it to the caller. But you're right probably a sample with a longer-term storage would be better.

Comment: @madreflection the whole idea makes no sense for why would he use this method. But within the problem scope this is the best answer i think. But again, the problem MAKES NO SENSE.

Comment: it should be staying in memory for long time, as it will be used for generating reports and tracking as well, believe me pal, it makes a lot of since.
The only thing I am missing is the conditional statement to check for the year, I don't want the serial number to continue counting if we have entered a new year.

Comment: I think the point @madreflection is making is that even if you make it past a year change, at some point the server will need to be rebooted for maintenance and you'll lose whatever is in memory, so it's probably best to store this someplace more permanent, otherwise the numbers will start back at `1` again when the program is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You just use two seperate numbers and put them together to where you want them to show.

You have a method `IncrementCurrentNumber` that just increases the first number:

```
int currentNumber = 0;
void IncrementCurrentNumber()
{
  currentNumber++;
}
```

And you have another method that increases the year and resets the current number:

int year = 2019;

```
void IncrementYear()
{
  year++;
  currentNumber = 0;
}
```

Then you get the actual serial number by joining both:

```
string GetNextSerialNumber()
{
  IncrementCurrentNumber();
  return currentNumber+"/"+year;
}
```

And whenever you want to increment year, e.g. with a button, you call the `IncrementYear()` method.

Edit: And the comments are of course right, if you want it to automatically use the current year, you'll have to use DateTime.Now.Year to get that and also have the program remember the last serial number, so you can check whether or not you have to reset the `currentNumber`.